# CSS selector to find the first tbody

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

#### My HTML code

```
<div id="myelement">
    <table class="myclass">
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>something</td>
               <td>
                   <table>
                       <tbody>
                         <tr> hari </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              foo
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

#### Xpath solution

`"//tbody[1]"`

#### Problem

I am looking for a CSS expression which should select first `tbody` which is a direct child of `table`, not the one inside `tr`.

If I use the CSS as `tbody`, then it would select 2, but I am looking for a way to fix it here. I know `table>tbody` will work, I am looking for if any more is there or not. As in my case I can't use `table>tbody`.

Comment: There is no way to select only the first one without using `>`

Comment: @Babai, take a look at my answer without >

Comment: how about td:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

Comment: @Danield I want to select `tbody` first one not the nested one.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 tbody tr td:first-of-type {
     color: red;
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xkk88/2/)

`td:first-of-type` will works too.

---

`:nth-of-type(1)` and `:first-of-type` are the same. [Docs](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afirst-of-type)

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [immediate child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `>`:

```
.myclass > tbody
```

Or if you just want the first one inside that `div`, you can do:

```
#myelement:first-child tbody
```

Comment: Does it select the first `tbody` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36207/discussion-between-babai-and-mattytommo)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `>`. It will only select elements that are a direct descendant of another element

```
.myClass > tbody
```

Make sure to specify the class of the table so that you don't select the table further down in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

This selector below will select the first `tbody` inside the table with class `myclass`, and not the one inside the descendant `tr`.

```
table.myclass > tbody
```